# How to append an inline template element with modified (id) content to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below in the example, I want that each time when the add button is clicked to take the element inside the **template div** and append it to the **landingzone class** element. But at the same time I need the **NEWID** to change for the new element. Of course this is just an example, the table stuff can be a div or anything else.

the form:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="title">
   <input type="text" name="number">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr> <th>Parts</th> </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="landingzone">
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Save">
   <input type="button" name"add" class="add" value="Save">
</form>
```

the template:

```
<div class="template" style="display: hidden">
   <tr id="NEWID">
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="part_NEWID">
      </td>
   </tr>       
</div>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us what you have tried. So we can start from that to discuss you issue.

Comment: You are right @Andrea. I am sorry for this time. I have red the link and will ask a more detailed and understandable question next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example for your need. The javascript will work without changing any html except in place of `name"add"` should be `name="add"`

What i have done here is i'm getting the id of the `template tr` and setting it with increment and also the `input` field name.

```js
var $landingzone = $('.landingzone');
var $add = $('.add');
var desiredId = 'id';
$add.on('click', function() {
  var $template = $('.template').find('tr');
  var id = $template.attr('id');
  var idArr = id.split('-');
  if (!idArr[1]) {
    id = desiredId + '-1';
  } else {
    id = desiredId + '-' + (parseInt(idArr[1]) + 1);
  }
  $template.attr('id', id);
  $template.find('input').attr('name', 'part_'+id);
  console.log('input id--->'+id, 'input name--->'+'part_'+id);
  $landingzone.append($template.clone());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <input type="text" name="number">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Parts</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="landingzone">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
  <input type="button" name="add" class="add" value="Add">
</form>

<table class="template" style="display: none">
  <tr id="NEWID">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="part_NEWID">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Andrea said in her comment, some more details would be appreciated ...

I think what you are after is:

```
const $template = $('.template').clone()
$template.attr('id', 'someId')
$template.find('input[name="part_NEWID"]').attr('name', 'part_someId')
$('.landingzone').append($template)
```

And if you need it in a function:

```
function appendTemplateToLandingZone (newId) {
  const $template = $('.template').clone()
  $template.attr('id', newId)
  $template.find('input[name="part_NEWID"]').attr('name', 'part_' + newId)
  $('.landingzone').append($template)
}
```

I haven't tested this, so it might need a slight adjustment. If you'll provide a basic [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/) I'll make it work there.

Comment: Thx @goldylucks . Will prepare jsbin or jsfiddle next time.